# How to undo git rm . -r --cached command without losing any uncommitted changes?

Tags: git, rm

I've accidentally executed a `git rm . -r --cached` command which makes all files have deleted status. I have some uncommitted changes which I do not want to lose. How can I undo the effects of `git rm . -r --cached` command and return to the previous state without losing any uncommitted changes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you used the `--cached` option, only your index has been modified. Your working directory has been left as is. You can simply `git add` files marked as deleted.

Comment: Do i need to commit after git add . command? If that is the case, it would increase one more commit which has no meaning to history log as it's done accidentally.

Comment: @akash88 nop. no commit.

Comment: Done with  git add. now status is good for all fine except for those file which are not in gitignore file list ? git add . command do not undelete files which are place in gitignore file?

Comment: @akash88 if I recall, files in .gitignored can't be added with a simple `git add .`. You need either to add them individually or force them to be added.

Answer (score 3):

Just add them again with: `git add .`

The command you ran doesn't remove the files from the disk, just from the index. So, add them  back.

Comment: Not sure, what would stash do in this case? Do i need to commit after git add . command? If that is the case, it would increase one more commit which has no meaning to history log as it's done accidently.

Comment: The first add action will safely undo the "rm" you called. Now I understood that this was by accident. Just edited my answer, thought you wanted to perform the "rm" command and then recover the changes.

Comment: Thanks !!! I've done with  git add. now status is good for all fine except for those file which are not in gitignore file list ? git add . command do not undelete files which are placed in gitignore file?

Comment: Git add only works in the index, so it will never undelete something, but rather add the changes to the index before a commit.